# What does "hairy strings" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From Claire Keegan's novel *Small Things Like These*

> Chimneys threw out smoke which fell away and drifted off in hairy, drawn-out strings before dispersing along the quays.

I cannot catch the meaning of "hairy, drawn-out strings".
Maybe "drawn-out" means "long",but what is "hairy strings"?

Comment: Why have you not said what novel, and who wrote it?

Comment: Imagine a long string of smoke. Then imagine it has thin tendrils smoke, like hairs.

Comment: From Claire Keegan's novel "Small Things Like These".

Comment: I checked a dictionary, it says 'hairy' means " a hairy person or animal has a lot of hair on their body." So I confused. You said it means only hair-like, right?

Comment: It's just imagery, trying to describe the drifting and curling smoke.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then, this sentence means that the smoke exhaled from chimneys eventually flowed into a long, thin, trailing single thread, right?

Comment: It says **strings**, so it flowed into several threads. Either the 'strings' were like hairs, or they had lots of shorter threads coming off them like something hairy.

Comment: The image that comes to mind are frizzy strands of yarn.

Answer (score 2):

This is a metaphor.  The smoke is not hairy string, but it is like hairy string in some way.  Probably the smoke is in a long stream of smoke (like a string) with little clouds of smoke around it (like hair).

This is not a common figure of speech, it has been invented my the author to create an image. You can surely think of similar examples in your own language, so there is nothing special about English in this use.